# How to get properties in multiple reducer by using useSelector() hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm new on React-redux Hooks.
I've had the confusing about useSelector() hook.
An example: i had 3 Reducers

- mapUtilityActionReducer include {openDirectionInstruction}
- cameraMapReducer include {pitch, bearing, zoom}
- changeMapPropertyReducer include {centerMapLongitude, centerMaplatitude}

1. With the React-redux: i can extract data from reducer by using the mapStateToProps. if i want to get data from multiple reducer, i just had to define

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const {openDirectionInstruction} = state.mapUtilityActionReducer;
  const {pitch, bearing} = state.cameraMapReducer;
  const {centerMapLongitude, centerMaplatitude} = state.changeMapPropertyReducer;
  return {
    openDirectionInstruction,
    pitch,
    bearing,
    centerMapLongitude, 
    centerMaplatitude
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MapBoxComponent)
```

if zoom value of cameraMapReducer is changed, the MapBoxComponent isn't re-rendered.

2. If i use useSelector() hook for functional component
   I have tried

```js
const openDirectionInstruction = useSelector(state => state.mapUtilityActionReducer.openDirectionInstruction);
const pitch = useSelector(state => state.cameraMapReducer.pitch);
const bearing = useSelector(state => state.cameraMapReducer.bearing);
const centerMapLongitude = useSelector(state => state.changeMapPropertyReducer.centerMapLongitude);
const centerMapLongitude = useSelector(state => state.changeMapPropertyReducer.centerMapLongitude);
```

It still works but this way was not good because if i need more data, i have to write a lot of lines.
How do i can retrieve those properties by using useSelector() hook to get the same result as the mapStateToProps without writing multiple useSelector()?
I tried

```js
const mapbox = useSelector(state => {
    return {
      pitch: state.MapBoxReducer.pitch,
      bearing: state.MapBoxReducer.bearing
    }
 })
```

and i got extracted data but when the zoom property in MapBoxReducer changed, this MapBoxComponent will be re-rendered too although i don't wanna use it.
Thanks a lot!
Sorry for my bad english.